# SQL Server 2000 FTP

Tags: ftp, sql-server-2000, dts

I'm trying to use SQL Server 2000 DTS Package to download a file from a FTP server.  However, the FTP module in DTS only shows the files in my ftp login "Home" directory.  I need to change the remote directory once I've connected.  How do I do this?  I can quite happily browse to the directory in the Files tab of the FTP task.  The directory I need to browse is 'above' my home directory.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a "Dynamic Property Task" one step before the FTP Task.

Change the FTP Task setting for SourceFilename.  It is just a Constant.

Source Value should be:
'FILENAME';'/FTPSTARTUP/PATH';'FILESIZE'